# Using Australian mobile in China

Tags: china, australia, mobile-operators, cellphones

Will I be able to use an Australian mobile phone (3 Network) in China?  I know that I can do international roaming but I am unsure about any frequency differences.

Answer (score 6):

I have an iPhone 4 on Telstra's 3G network and it switched over immediately as soon as I switched it on in China.

I immediately received an SMS telling me that data was disabled, but could be switched on at a cost. I just used wifi hotspots for data as necessary.

The phone switched over to [China Telecom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Telecom)'s network and call quality and coverage were excellent.